# list the last 10 rows from sql and print it in marquee

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

How to list the last 10 rows in sql ?

I've used `"SELECT * FROM event ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1"` before and its was effective for me, thought playing with it might works.

I used `"SELECT * FROM event ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 10"`

```
"SELECT TOP 10 * FROM event ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1"
```

and "SELECT * FROM event ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 10,999999"
but doesn't work.

this is the php file

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("rock","mido","1234","fyp");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM event ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1");
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ;

 {

  echo $row['EventName'] . $row['Date'] . $row['Time'] . $row['Venue'] . $row['Note'];

  }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

and the most important, is there anyway to make display as one by one?
I should I try `marquee` with with it ?

Comment: "SELECT * FROM event ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 10" what's the problem with that? should work

Comment: Given `ID` is a auto incremental field using `ORDER BY id DESC` will order it from the last entry to the first entry and limiting it to 10 will display the last 10 entries. Is there a problem using that one? Or if you have a `DATETIME` field you can also use that one. Is there any specific reason you're looking for another way to do it?

Comment: @oschlueter its just showing row number 10

Comment: I'm not looking for another way but ORDER BY ID DESC and limiting it to 10 doesn't work as I need it

Comment: @opa.mido your code have no `while` so its only obvious it will give u a single result. [**See this example.**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) As for showing 1 by 1 you will need to learn HTML and CSS.

Comment: @Prix thanx man appreciate it ... I'm learning it currently

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM event ORDER BY ID LIMIT 10 OFFSET (SELECT COUNT(*) - 11 FROM event);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to change the `order by`:

```
SELECT *
FROM event
ORDER BY ID ASC
LIMIT 10;
```

If you want them ordered by `id` descending, you can use a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM event
      ORDER BY ID ASC
      LIMIT 10
     ) e
ORDER BY ID DESC;
```